# Making whole table searchable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make the table searchable using a search bar. I have added a code but its only searching on the first column of the table. I want to make all the columns of the table searchable. Can you please guide me how can i do that? Here is my code.

```
$("#search").on("keyup", function() {
    var value = $(this).val();

    $(".table tr").each(function(index) {
        if (index !== 0) {

            $row = $(this);

            var id = $row.find("td:first").text();

            if (id.indexOf(value) !== 0) {
                $row.hide();
                //$row.html('Records not found!');

                //$(".norecord").html('<td colspan="9">Records not found!</td>');
            }
            else {
                $row.show();

            }
        }


    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the ':first' from your query `$row.find("td").text()` should return the texts of all columns of that row.

Answer (score 0):

I would use regex instead of "indexOf". something like this:

```
if ($(this).text().search(new RegExp(value, "i")) > -1) {
    $(this).parents("tr").show();
} else {
    $(this).parents("tr").hide();
}
```

DEMO: https://jsfiddle.net/7qkgf14d/1/

And then, later on, if you want, you can specify by what column you want to search by.